# IComparable doesn't need to be contravariant?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, contravariance, icomparable

In the code below i am targetting the .NET 2.0 Framework.

I can pass a Programmer (derived) object to the Compare method which expects a Person (base class)

But since a Programmer IS A Person (simple OO concept) i claim that in .NET 4.0 the 'in' keyword in the IComparable interface declaration is 'overkill' :)

Before i write an email to Microsoft about them removing the in keyword please try to convince me otherwise :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person();

        var test = person.CompareTo(new Programmer());
    }
}

internal class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return this.Id - other.Id;
    }
}

class Programmer : Person
{
    public string ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Actually plz just help me make 'get' this.. :)

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out what the question is. Can you clarify the question? I suspect that you might simply be confused about what the difference is between variance and assignment compatibility; they are often confused. Try reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that link but at the moment i get "Sorry, there was a problem with your last request!"

Hope thats temporary...

Comment: The link is working and useful indeed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Co- and contravariance is not about the types you pass into the methods. It is about the generic interfaces that *contain* the methods.

With `in` the following code is legal:

```
IComparable<Person> foo = ...;
IComparable<Programmer> bar = foo;
```

Without the `in` it would be illegal.

Comment: Indeed the code you supply here does compile in .NET4 but not in .NET2. I think you guys are right and i am mixing up concepts here.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if an `IComparer<>` implementation can compare `Person` instances, then it can compare objects of types derived from `Person`. The `in` keyword allows you to use an `IComparer<Person>` comparer to compare objects of type `MyPerson` (derived from `Person`). An example use case is a comparer that orders `Person` instances by name for use in a `SortedList<Person>`; where the contravariant interface also allows the same comparer to be used with `SortedList<MyPerson>`.